# Get type of Class from generic Class(of T)

Tags: .net, vb.net, generics

I am trying to get the Type of a class which is generic.  Most questions revolve around people trying to retrieve the Type T from a `List(Of T)` for example.  Instead I want the Type of the class itself, i.e. System.Collections.Generic.List

I am trying the following code, but it returns the Type including the generic parameter.  If I then try to create an instance of the class with a *different* generic Type I get an error because the Type is closed.

```
'The type I want to use a a Generic Parameter in a new object
dim O = MasterObject 

'This is the class which is Generic    
dim BaseType as Type = me.getType 

'This is the line that errors, since BaseType already has a Generic Type
dim GenericType as Type=BaseType.MakeGenericType(O.getType())

'This would be the new object, with a new generic type
dim NewObject as Object = Activator.CreateInstance(GenericType,vars)
```

So is there either a way to clear a generic parameter from a Type or some way of extracting the Type without Generic Parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get *opened* one calling [`Type.GetGenericTypeDefinition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getgenerictypedefinition(v=vs.110).aspx).

BTW, if you really know that you're going to create an instance of `List<T>`, you can get the generic type definition using `GetType(List(Of T))`.

Comment: @CodeCaster Yeah... I've edited it. I thought OP thought that actual type is just `List` ;(

Comment: Thanks! Sorry should have been clear my example of List was just an example... in fact my type is going to be one of many types of inherited sub-class.... but your answer works perfectly.  I can mark it as correct in 2 minutes :-)